# Trying to do min of 2 dataframes with element of one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two DataFrames and I'm trying to do that min of one based on values in the other, here is a sample:

aggDF

`someDate, someVal`

```
1/1/2010 5
1/1/2011 6
1/1/2012 7
1/1/2013 8
```

currDF

`otherDate`

```
1/1/2009
1/1/2010
6/1/2010
```

desired outputDF (having the dates not super important, if I only get the myVal that would be fine):

`otherDate myVal`

```
1/1/2009 5
1/1/2010 5
6/1/2010 6
```

I feel like the way I am doing it right now is too convoluted/slow:

```
outputDF = [aggDF[aggDF.someDate >= currDate] for currDate in currDF.otherDate]
outputDF = [outputDF[i]['someVal'] for i in range(0, len(outputDF)]
outputDF = [outputDF[i].iloc[0] for i in range(0, len(outputDF)]
```

Surely there is some better way to do what I am trying to do. I would appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I believe [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) is what you're looking for. Here is the example which gives your desired output.

```
aggdf = pd.DataFrame({'someDate': ['1/1/2010', '1/1/2011',
                                   '1/1/2012', '1/1/2013'],
                      'someVal': [5,6,7,8]})

currdf = pd.DataFrame({'otherDate': ['1/1/2009', '1/1/2010',
                                     '6/1/2010']})

aggdf['someDate'] = pd.to_datetime(aggdf['someDate'])
currdf['otherDate'] = pd.to_datetime(currdf['otherDate'])

pd.merge_asof(currdf, aggdf, direction='forward',
              left_on='otherDate', right_on='someDate')
```

Out:

```
    otherDate   someDate    someVal
0   2009-01-01  2010-01-01  5
1   2010-01-01  2010-01-01  5
2   2010-06-01  2011-01-01  6
```